# Django form FileField error 'This Field is required'

Tags: django, forms, validation, file-upload

I am receiving a This field is required error using a form view that django is generating.
I have a Scan model that looks like:

```
class Scan(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('Created', auto_now=True)
    data = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')

    def __str__(self):
        return str("{}-{}".format(self.device, self.created_at))
```

I have a CreateView defined:

```
class ScanCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Scan
    fields = '__all__'
```

My url route is

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('scan/create/', views.ScanCreate.as_view(), name='scan-create'),
    ...
]
```

and finally a scan_form.html template

```
    {% block content %}
  <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

On picking a file to upload and submitting the form, I get the 'This field is required.' error and the request fails:

[image: post submission 'This field is required.' error]
The file has been selected for upload so why would django report field is required?

Comment: `auto_now` sets the field to `editable=False` iirc.

Comment: Thanks Willem, I tried passing `editable=True` but that has no effect. Removing `auto_add` does make the field appear but there is no default value which I need. Can I have the field appear and contain a default value?

Comment: I think you misunderstand it. By setting it to `auto_now`, you basically specify that this is non-editable field. So it indeed should not show up.

Comment: I understand now. It seems that the error message may apply to the `data` FileField, updating question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main problem in you code is that you are not using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form, so when the request is sent to the server, it does not have the file in the `request.FILES` collection.

you have to write the html code for your form like this:

```
{% block content %}
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

and ensure that the action is pointing to the correct URL.

finally, this is the documentation for file uploads: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/file-uploads/